# Vertical scrolling will not scroll to end of list

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve a vertical scroll. But for some reason it won't scroll all the way to the end of the list.

I am working with angular

Here is a codepen of my code example -> http://codepen.io/GY22/pen/PqeoZv

html code:

```
<!-- START SIDEBAR -->
<div id="sidebar" ng-app="DragDrop" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users" class="circular">
      <p class="initials">{{user.initials}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- END SIDEBAR -->
```

css code:

```
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  z-index: 33;
  margin-top: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 100px
}

#userList {
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}

ul li {
  margin-left: -22px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.initials {
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

angular code:

```
var contentEditor = angular.module("DragDrop", []);

contentEditor.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.users = [{
    initials: 'GY'
  }, {
    initials: 'XX'
  }, {
    initials: 'KK'
  }, {
    initials: 'TT'
  }, {
    initials: 'AA'
  }, {
    initials: 'QQ'
  }, {
    initials: 'PP'
  }, {
    initials: 'SS'
  }, {
    initials: 'MM'
  }, {
    initials: 'RS'
  }, {
    initials: 'KL'
  }, {
    initials: 'CJ'
  }, {
    initials: 'RT'
  }, {
    initials: 'DJ'
  }, {
    initials: 'XG'
  }, {
    initials: 'XX'
  }];

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the height of `#sidebar` to `100%` instead of a fixed height.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you set the height of a div (#sidebar) to 900px and the container where the div resides is smaller (say 400px) - you will not be able to see the last 500px of the div (#sidebar).

If you want the height to be 100% of the current window - try using height: 100% instead:

```
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 33;
  margin-top: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 100px
}
```

See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOjYKv

Answer (score 0):

You've set a fixed height of 900px for the `#sidebar`. By changing this value to a smaller one you'll achieve the wanted result.